# Getting crop coordinates from a resized image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, popup, jcrop

I'm working on a popup where the user can choose an image, crop it and then upload the croped area. The problem is that if the user choose a big image the popup goes very big so I tried to give the img a fixed size (or put it in a fixed div) but that ruined the coordinates that I get from the crop function (I use Jcrop btw).
So the question is haw can I get correct crop coortinates from a resized image.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment to ask for details, so here is an answer based on what I understand. If you want a more precise answer, you should add some code (the way you resize image, how you use Jcrop, etc).
As I understand, the user choose the area to crop on a resized image.

What you can do is calculate the resizing ratio.
Let's say the image was `900*900px` and you resize it to be `300*300px` max.
In this case, the ratio is `900/300=3` (`originalWidth/resizedWidth`).
All you have to do is multiply the coordinates of the cropping by this ratio.

Make sure that your ratio works both for width and height (that depends on the way you resize the image). If you image isn't a square you may have to calculate 2 ratios (one for the height and one for the width).
In the case you have to multiply all x values by the `widthRatio` and all y values by the `heightRatio`.

Comment: that's what i'm working at right now.Thanks for help

Comment: It worked when the user choose an image that is bigger then the fixed div or img .... but it didnt work with smaller ones

Comment: @MehdiSayeb With smaller ones, if you resize them like the big one, the ratio should work correctly. But are you resizing images that are smaller ? If not you shouldn't use a ratio but the real image size for image that are not resized. Again I can't really answer precisely without seeing code, but I hope it helps.

Comment: so i didnt resize the smaller ones and everything is fine now thank you